# Can't write em dash and en dash in LibreOffice on Kubuntu

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, libreoffice, unicode-entry

I have got a problem with writing em dash and en dash in LibreOffice on Kubuntu.

When I push <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> and type *2013* or *2014*, LibreOffice doesn't generate en dash or em dash.

Comment: Yes I can see underlined u, but when I write 2013 underline disappired.

Comment: This problem manifested only in Libreoffice.

Comment: libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer/bionic-updates,now 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 amd64

Comment: libreoffice-base/bionic-updates,now 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 amd64

Comment: And many another outputs.

Comment: What output do you think is important?

Comment: libreoffice-kde/bionic-updates,bionic-updates,now 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 all [instalovaný]
libreoffice-kde4/bionic-updates,now 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 amd64 [instalovaný]

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is but you could try first closing all LibreOffice applications and running `sudo apt purge libreoffice-kde` and `sudo apt purge libreoffice-kde`. Then run `sudo apt install libreoffice-kde5`. I'm not saying this **will** fix your problem. So if it doesn't work, just go back to what you had.

Comment: It does not work, but thank you for answer.

Comment: This potentially can be a bug that needs to be submitted to maintaiers. Please open a terminal and type `ubuntu-bug libreoffice-kde` and press Enter. Then follow onscreen instructions, and once browser opens up, explain the problem as completely as you can.